# pointPlacement does not work on spline

Tags: highcharts

I am using **highstock** and tried to move the points on a **spline serie** on the xAxis by setting `pointPlacement:0.5`. But it seems that it does not work on splines or lines. If I define the series as **column** it works as expected. With reference to the Highstock Options Reference I think this should work as well for other chart types as this option is also listed under the spline description

Is there any other way to get the points shifted along the xAxis.

I set up a jsfidle to demonstrate the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/pb4Mz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pointPlacement works only in the column chart.